# Why does this Standard ML expression equal 11?

Tags: function, pattern-matching, anonymous-function, sml, smlnj

Can anyone explain to me and help me understand why the following expression equals 11 in standard ML? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
(fn f => (fn g => f(g 2))) (fn n => n+3) (fn n => n*4)
```

Comment: By the way, it seems like you might want to revise your style of questions on StackOverflow to draw from the more general questions and answers that have already been asked. There's some kind of missing link between "Why is this 11?" and "[β-reductions in the λ-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus)" and the art of writing excellent questions is a balance between making it concrete enough (like you did) and generalizing the problem to a point where the answer can be used (and thus found) if the problem was formulated slightly different, e.g. if the result wasn't 11. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can evaluate the expression:

```
(fn f => (fn g => f(g 2))) (fn n => n+3) (fn n => n*4)
```

Here, replace `f` with `(fn n => n+3)` so it becomes

```
(fn g => (fn n => n+3)(g 2)) (fn n => n*4)
```

Similarly, replace `g` with `(fn n => n*4)` so it becomes

```
(fn n => n+3)((fn n => n*4) 2)
```

Similarly, replace either the first `n` with `((fn n => n*4) 2)` or the second `n` with `2`.

Answer (score 2):

Since this seems like homework I don't want to do more than give a hint.

One thing you can do is eliminate some of the lambda expressions in favor of explicit function definitions.

For example:

```
fun h f = (fn g => f(g 2))

fun f n = n + 3

fun g n = n*4
```

Then -- see if you can puzzle out why `h f g` evaluates to `11`.

As another hint, in ML function application is left-associative, hence `h f g` is the same as

```
(h f) g
```

This means the *function* `h f` (`h` returns functions) applied to the function `g`. Note that the functions that `h` returns are functions which take functions (such as `g`) as input and return integers (such as 11) as output.

As a final hint, how would you get from the number 2 to the number 11, using the two simple functions `f` and `g`?